# Why does printing 0100 print 64 in Java?

Tags: java, printing, numbers, int, bin

Why does

```
System.out.println(0100);
```

print 64 to the console?

Its not like its converting to binary.

Comment: `0100` is an _octal_ literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An integer starting with a 0 is interpreted in base 8 (as starting with 0x gives you base 16). Thus `0100` is `100` in base 8, which is `1 * 8^2 = 64`.

Comment: What is I wanted binary?

Comment: @Randy https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Comment: Prefix ```0b``` should wor for binary. ```System.out.println()``` will print in decimal. For binary output, you need some format function.